# Como saber se o campo cpf não existe no banco de dados?

Tags: java, jdbc

Exemplo do que estou tentando fazer:

```
    vRS = sql.executeQuery();
     while(vRS.next())
     {
         nome = vRS.getString("nome");
         cargo = vRS.getString("cargo");
     }
```

O que eu quero fazer é quando o registro nao existe para mostrar uma mensagem de System.out.Println("Não existe no banco!");

```
        if (!vRS.next()) {
            System.out.println("Não Encontrou cpf ou cnpj");
             setVerMensagem(true);
             setVerGrid(false);
        }
```

Essa forma funciona bugada qual seria a forma correta?

Comment: Como está a tabela com este campo? Porque não checa se o campo está nulo ou vazio?

Comment: Tipo eu quero validar o cpf com java, se o campo cpf nao existe na base é para mostrar uma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Tipo esse cpf vem da tela.

Comment: E a query no método checa se esse cpf existe

Comment: De onde está vindo esses dados? Essa variável RS é um vetor?

Comment: Adicione mais informações na pergunta, como o schema dessa sua tabela, e como você resgata os dados dessa tabela antes de checar se o campo não existe.

Comment: vRS é o resulSet os dados que vem do banco.

Comment: mas a tabela contem ou não o campo cpf/cnpf? Por isso é interessante mostrar o schema de qual tabela você quer checar esta informação.

Comment: possui o campo sim. Eu quero saber se existe o registro referente ao campo com id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você não deixou muitos detalhes do que está tentando fazer, vou deixar o código abaixo para testar

```
vRS = sql.executeQuery();
if (vRS != null) {
  while (vRS.next()) {
   nome = vRS.getString("nome");
   cargo = vRS.getString("cargo");
  }
} 
else {
  System.out.println("Não Encontrou cpf ou cnpj");
  setVerMensagem(true);
  setVerGrid(false);
}
```